# Calculating how many even/odd number in user input Python 2.7

Tags: python

I want to calculate the amount of even/odd numbers in the input in put in but when I make the formula for it it gives me an error:
in my case it has to have a loop and iteration in the code so cant change anything significantly.

```
exceptions.TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

The code:

```
count_odd = None
count_even = None

while True:
    numbers = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if numbers == "done": break

    try:
        num = int(numbers)
    except ValueError:
        print "Not a number"
        continue

for x in numbers:
        if x % 2: #error is here
            count_even+=1
        else:
            count_odd+=1

print("Number of even numbers :",count_even)
print("Number of odd numbers :",count_odd)
```

Comment: `numbers` is a string, not a list of integers. `x % 2` is attempting to perform string formatting.

Comment: Presumably the stack trace showing exactly where the error occurred has been omitted. Please don't do that.